# How to stop google maps from rendering direction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm creating a function to accept an array of point and display them on the maps as a single route.

```
function __RenderRoute(map, points, lineColor, DrawResult, i, callback, waitTime) {
    var tmpPoints = points.slice(i, i + 9);
    if (tmpPoints.length > 1) {
        var request = {
            origin: tmpPoints.shift().location,
            destination: tmpPoints.pop().location,
            waypoints: tmpPoints,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
    }
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                draggable: false,
                markerOptions: {
                    visible: false
                },
                polylineOptions: {
                    clickable: true,
                    strokeColor: lineColor,
                    strokeOpacity: .6,
                    strokeWeight: 6,
                    zIndex: 5
                },
                preserveViewport: true
            });
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
            DrawResult.directionDisplays.push(directionsDisplay);
        } else {
            console.log(status);
            console.log("Wait " + waitTime + " miliseconds.");
            setTimeout(function () { __RenderRoute(map, points, lineColor, DrawResult, i, callback, waitTime * 2) }, waitTime);
            return;
        }
        DrawResult.directionResults.push(result);
        if (i + 9 < points.length) {
            __RenderRoute(map, points, lineColor, DrawResult, i + 8, callback, 350);
        } else {
            if (callback != null) {
                callback();
            }
            DrawResult.completed = true;
        }
    });
}
```

However, as my array always contains a huge amount of point (usually more than 100), it's difficult to repeatedly invoke the function as the map would just freeze out to wait for previous request to complete. Is there anyway to stop google maps from rendering route, or stop the function from callback itself while waiting when you call it again?

Comment: I don't think this is the answer but what happens when the test `if (tmpPoints.length > 1)` fails? `request` will be undefined and `directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) ...` will either pick up `request` from an outer scope or throw an error.

Comment: Actually the tmpPoints.length always > 1. if (tmpPoints.length > 1) plays no significance. The reason it's still there is because I have not removed it.

Comment: `tmpPoints.length` may be greater than one today and tomorrow and the next day, but will it *always* be greater than one? [Defensive Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming).

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if Google will allow their limit of 8 waypoints to be overcome quite so simply but here goes.

I have modified `__RenderRoute()` with a view to :

- building a composite route object comprising the data of all directionsService.route segments, such that ...can be called once for the whole route
- returning a Promise that is resolved when all recursion is complete, or is rejected with a meaningful error message.

The main function `__RenderRoute()` :

```
function __RenderRoute(points, i, waitTime, dfrd, errorObj) {//<<<<< Now called with a reduced number of parameters
    dfrd = dfrd || $.Deferred();
    errorObj = errorObj || {
        count: 0,
        threshold: 5//adjust as necessary
    };
    var tmpPoints = points.slice(i, i + 9);
    if (tmpPoints.length < 2) {
        if (i == 0) {//top level call
            dfrd.reject("Not enough points");
            return dfrd.promise();
        }
        else { return; }
    }
    var request = {
        origin: tmpPoints.shift().location,
        destination: tmpPoints.pop().location,
        waypoints: tmpPoints,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    var route = new RouteResult();//Custom object that allows successive directionsService.route results to be componded into a single route.
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            route.add(result);//Hopefully magic happens here.
            if(i + 9 < points.length) {
                __RenderRoute(points, i+8, 350, dfrd, errorObj);
            } else {
                dfrd.resolve(route);//<<<<< Resolve the jQuery Deferred object
            }
        } else {
            console.log("google.maps.DirectionsService status = " + status);
            if(++errorObj.count < errorObj.threshold) {
                console.log("Wait " + waitTime + " miliseconds.");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    __RenderRoute(points, i, waitTime*2, dfrd, errorObj);
                }, waitTime);
            }
            else {
                dfrd.reject('Error threshold (' + errorObj.threshold + ') exceeded'); //Reject the jQuery Deferred object
            }
        }
    });
    return dfrd;
}
```

In a suitable scope define `directionsDisplay` :

```
//I think a DirectionsRenderer is reusable. If so `directionsDisplay` needs to be constructed only once as below. If not, then move this block inside foo().
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: false,
    markerOptions: {
        visible: false
    },
    polylineOptions: {
        clickable: true,
        strokeColor: '#99F',//adjust as desired
        strokeOpacity: .6,
        strokeWeight: 6,
        zIndex: 5
    },
    preserveViewport: true
});
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);//Assumed to be defined elsewhere
```

In a suitable scope define `RouteResult()` :

```
/*
 * RouteResult is a utility class that will (hopefully)
 * allow several routes to be compounded into one.
 * Based on information here :
 * - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions
 * -
 * This is experimental and untested.
 */
function RouteResult() {
    var r = {
        legs: [],
        waypoint_order: [],
        overview_path: [],
        copyrights: [],
        warnings: [],
        bounds : new google.maps.LatLngBounds()//initially empty LatLngBounds obj
    };
    this.add = function (result) {
        r.legs = r.legs.concat(result.legs);
        r.waypoint_order = r.waypoint_order.concat(result.waypoint_order);
        r.overview_path = r.overview_path.concat(result.overview_path);
        r.copyrights = r.copyrights.concat(result.copyrights);
        r.warnings = r.warnings.concat(result.warnings);

        r.bounds = r.bounds.union(result.bounds);//???
        //or possibly just
        //r.bounds.union(result.bounds);//???
    };
    this.get = function() { return r; };
}
```

Then, call `__RenderRoute()`, as follows :

```
//foo() is an assumed function from which __RenderRoute() is called.
function foo() {
    ...
    //__RenderRoute returns a Promise, allowing `.done()` and `.fail()` to be chained.
    __RenderRoute(points, 0, 350).done(function(route) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(route.get());//route is a custom object. .get() returns the actuual route. 
        //You can safely call __RenderRoute() again here, eg. with `setTimeout(foo, delay)`.
    }).fail(function(errMessage) {
        console.log(errMessage);
    });
    ...
}
```

- See comments in code.
- Untested, so will probably need to be debugged.
- If it doesn't work, maybe it will give you some ideas.